# java google appspot application can I move to another server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Its possible to move my app hosted in appspot.com to another server.
If so what are the steps and requirements?
My app its done in eclipse using gae java

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to take your code exactly as it is now, set it up in a different server and work. Even if your whole code is App Engine agnostic, your datastore models are probably not. Thus, first you need to define which is the development environment you want to move to, and then modify your code to properly work on that.

As far as your current data are concerned, you need to create a "migration tool" that will get the data from App Engine and import them to your new environment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Google Appengine doesn't provide any controls over what host(s) your code runs on. If you've set up a paid app, you can change the memory/cpu profile on the **Application Settings** which could be assumed to require an instance of your app to run in a different virtual machine. You can also shutdown an instance (on the **Instances** page). If there are no instances running, a new one will be created on the next request, and is unlikely to run on the same virtual machine as the one that was running the app before.